# add an image to a select tag

Tags: html, css, image, select

```
<div class = "select-color">
  <h6>Colours (30 available)</h6>
       <select class="select-dropdown formcontrol" name="colour" id="colour">
         <option value="choose" disabled selected="selected">Select colour</option>
         <option class="colourList" value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
       </select>
  <img src="images/selector.png" class="spin">
</div>
```

This is the html that I have and this is the css for it

```
.select-dropdown {
     cursor: pointer; font-size: 20px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;       /* remove default arrow */
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    background: url(images/selector.png) 96% / 15% no-repeat;
}
```

I am trying, as you can see, to add the selector.png image on the right side of the selector tag but it doesn't work as I expected. I've seen others have done it with the background but for some unknown reason it doesn't work for me.

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgB22.png)

Comment: Can you show us your working code? Added [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) or on [codepen](http://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position:relative` on the parent element. And then use `position:absolute` on `spin` to absolutely position it as required inside the parent `select-color`.

What you need is:

```css
 .select-color{
  position:relative;
 }
 /*added above*/
 
 .select-dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* remove default arrow */
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  background: url(images/selector.png) 96% / 15% no-repeat;
  width:200px;/*added this. remove it.*/
}

/*added below*/
.spin{
  width:15px;
  position:relative;
  left:-30px;/*adjust accordingly*/
}
```

```html
<div class="select-color">
  <h6>Colours (30 available)</h6>
  <select class="select-dropdown formcontrol" name="colour" id="colour">
         <option value="choose" disabled selected="selected">Select colour</option>
         <option class="colourList" value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
       </select>
  <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/10897-200.png" class="spin">
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use absolute positioning because I am using scalable values to make the page responsive like : vw,vh,em,etc so I don't want to mess with absolute positioning + I need that arrow image integrated into my select because I though doing a simulation like <div><select><img></div> In which I display select and img inline-block and I delete de select's attribute and make that div look like an input